# How to generate numbers upto n using a loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Actually here I am trying to generate numbers like this.
1.0
1.1
...
1.9
2.0
2.1
...
2.9 upto N. Can someone please guide me how can I generate numbers in that format using loop.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking but `[...Array(n * 10)].map((_, i) => i / 10)`?

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for reply. Actually here I am trying to generate number in above format. On the basis of index.

Comment: @mplungjan Actually I want to generate numbers within a map only.

Comment: `((index+10)/10).toFixed(1)`

Comment: @Kanekar I converted my comment to answer and added a loop version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the returned arrays are STRINGS since JS will drop zeros after the decimal point

One-liner without loop

```js
const genFloats = n => [...Array(n+10)] // generate array
  .map((_, i) => (i / 10).toFixed(1))   // process the indicii of the array
  .slice(10); // drop the first 10


console.log(genFloats(20))
```

Loop:

```js
const genFloats = n => { 
  const res = [];
  for (let i=10;i<=n*10;i++) {
    console.log(i,i/10)
    res.push((i/10).toFixed(1)); 
  }  
  return res
};
console.log(genFloats(5))
```

Comment: mplungjan I am accepting your answer but can you please print that numbers within a map or for loop that will be more understandable to me if you can. because I am new to programming.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. You can add braces and console logs if you want `for (....) { console.log(i,i/10); res.push(...);}`

Comment: its okay I will do that, I was trying to saying as you printed console.log outside the map I want to print that console.log within a map function not outside as you printed. anyways thanks a ton for giving your valuable time here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `((index+10)/10).toFixed(1)`

```js
const arr = Array.from({length:20},(_,i) => ({a:`Item #${i+1}`}))

const res = arr.map((o,i) => ({...o, num:((i+10)/10).toFixed(1)}))

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and giving the time here.